# that vs in that

Tags: difference, demonstrative-pronouns

[ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/in-that):
**(1)** *I’ve been lucky **in that** I have never had to worry about money*.
my variant:
**(2)** *I’ve been lucky **that** I have never had to worry about money*.

Is (2) correct?
If not, then why not?
If it is, then what's the difference between (1) and (2)?

---

[ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/boast):
**(3)** *Philip’s boast is **that** he started out without any outside financial backing*.
my variant:
**(4)** *Philip’s boast is **in that** he started out without any outside financial backing*.

Is (4) correct?
If not, then why not?
If it is, then what's the difference between (3) and (4)?

---

Could you compare please "*that*" and "*in that*"?:
What is the difference between them?
When can we use only "*in that*"?
When can we use only "*that*"?
When can we use both "*in that*" and "*that*"?

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a concept of "syntactically correct" for #1 and #2 - they're both idiomatically valid (but the ***in*** version is far less common).

But for the other pair, #4 is syntactically invalid. My advice is unless you're ***quite sure*** your context is one where native speakers might use ***in that*** - mostly, when it means *[specifically] **because*** - you should stick to plain ***that***.

Approximately, ***in that...** = in **the specific respect** that...*